# FPDF - Generate multiple pdf in a single creation

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to generate multiple (in cluster) pdf reports using fpdf in a single click in a php form.

The test_center is the cluster of separate reports. When the submit button is clicked, it will call the php file of fpdf.  And my codes aren't working yet.

So far in my php:

```
<?php
$program="select distinct test_center  from sa_sase_result where school_year = '$content' ";
$prog=mysql_query($program);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($prog))
{
    echo '<option>' .$row['test_center'] . '</option>';      
}  

$message = null;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    if(!isset($_POST['depchair'])) {

    } else if($_POST['depchair']=="") {

    } else {            
        $input_depchair = addslashes($_POST['depchair']);                       

        $input_depchair = addslashes($_POST['depchair']);
        $pro_email="select control_no  from sa_student_infoe y where y.test_center = '$input_depchair'";
        $pro_address=mysql_query($pro_email);

        $address = mysql_result($pro_address, 0);
    }                   
}
?>
```

EDIT: Here's the generate_pdf.php file.

```
<?php

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');


 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("final") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM sa_student_infoe, sa_student_edubg, sa_sase_result, sa_accounts";
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
      $control_no[] = $row['control_no'];
      $surname[] = $row['surname'];
      $fname[] = $row['fname'];
      $mname[] = $row['mname'];
      $app_no[] = $row['activation_code'];
      $schoolyear[] = $row['schoolyear'];
      $schl[] = $row['high_school'];
      $schl_ad[] = $row['address_school']; 
      $apt[] = $row['aptitude']; 
      $mth[] = $row['math'];
      $lng[] = $row['language'];
      $sci[] = $row['science'];
      $totgrd[] = $row['total_grade'];
      $sx[] = $row['sex'];

      }

 $ctrl_no = array_shift( $control_no );
 $sname = array_shift( $surname );
 $firstname = array_shift( $fname );
 $midname = array_shift( $mname );
 $appno = array_shift( $app_no );
 $schyear = array_shift( $schoolyear );
 $school = array_shift( $schl );
 $school_ad = array_shift( $schl_ad );
 $aptitude = array_shift( $apt );
 $math = array_shift( $mth );
 $lang = array_shift( $lng );
 $science = array_shift( $sci );
 $gr = array_shift( $totgrd );
 $sex = array_shift( $sx );


$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','', 12);


$pdf->Cell(0, 0,'Mindanao State University', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10,'System Admission and Scholarship Examination (SASE)', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 20,'REPORT OF RATING', 0, 1, 'C');


$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Control No:');
$pdf->Cell(100,5,$ctrl_no);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'School Year:');
$pdf->Cell(-160,5,$schyear);
$pdf->Cell(30,15,'Activation Code:');
$pdf->Cell(10,15,'   ' . $appno);


$pdf->Cell(50,40,$sname);
$pdf->Cell(50,40,$firstname);
$pdf->Cell(-120,40,$midname);
$pdf->Cell(15,50,'____________________________________________________________________');
$pdf->Cell(50,60,'LASTNAME');
$pdf->Cell(50,60,'FIRSTNAME');
$pdf->Cell(-50,60,'MIDDLENAME');

$pdf->Cell(-65,90,$school);
$pdf->Cell(67,100,'____________________________________________________________________');
$pdf->Cell(-15,110,'SCHOOL');

$pdf->Cell(-52,140,$school_ad);
$pdf->Cell(57,150,'____________________________________________________________________');
$pdf->Cell(-25,160,'SCHOOL ADDRESS');

$pdf->Cell(.1,190,'--------------------------------------------------------------------');
$pdf->Cell(-35,200,'--------------------------------------------------------------------'); 

$pdf->Cell(17,230,'AP(30):');
$pdf->Cell(18,230,$aptitude);
$pdf->Cell(17,230,'LU(80):');
$pdf->Cell(18,230,$lang);
$pdf->Cell(17,230,'MA(40):');
$pdf->Cell(18,230,$math);
$pdf->Cell(17,230,'SC(30):');
$pdf->Cell(18,230,$science);
$pdf->Cell(18,230,'GR(180):');
$pdf->Cell(-300,230,$gr);  


$pdf->Cell(-10,260,'SEX:');


$pdf->Output("pdf_reports/SASE_report_rating/".$ctrl_no.".pdf", "F");


?>
```

Comment: ... and what the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. It won't generate multiple reports at a time.

Comment: what fields going to be in report and what is `<option>` output? just because i can not reproduce the output, can you expose output as screen capture?

Comment: The fields (like the name, age, etc ) are in a separate php file for fpdf. the <option> there is for the html code where a user can select which cluster that he needs to create reports. A cluster is a group of students. So a user is basically creating reports of students in a chosen cluster.

Comment: Sure, i'll upload a screen shot.

Comment: So far I understood the problem, you want to GENERATE multipage pdf file, where the data will taken from a sql query to database. If I am right, all you need, just code for some `generated-pdf.php` file to link with the dark-gray rectangle button. Is it exactly you want to see?

Comment: Yes you're right. And I already have that 'generated-pdf.php' file and have it linked in the html form. My problem is that I don't know how to generate multiple pdf at once (one click).

Comment: what is `multiple pdf generation`? you mean you want to see couple pdf's on a single page in containers or you want to deliver them in a single zip file as an attachment?

Comment: I just want to generate multiple pdf's and save them in a local directory. I'll upload my generate.php file.

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
$("#id_of_generate_it_button").click(function () {
    var N = 10;// ten pdf files will be generated and stored to the disk
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {// 'the loop' -- walk thru all parallel generation processes connected to the event
        parameter = N;// just to definite each single generated file
        $.get("generate.php?q=parameter", function (data) {// start the ajax process to generate single document
                                                           // ?q=parameter i wrote just for passing to the php file some dependent parameter for each single file 
            // pdf #i generated
        });
    }// end for parallel generating N pdf files to the disk
});//end click
```

in `generate.php`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sa_student_infoe, sa_student_edubg, sa_sase_result, sa_accounts WHERE some_field = ' . $_REQUEST['q'] . '";// single record from all
```

Comment: Thank you for not giving up on me. I'm not familiar with javascript(js), can you help me walk through it?

Comment: It is just template for you. I can not see where is in your generation code definition of each single file. This php will used for generation different files, which means this code have to read `$_REQUEST['q']` and make selection in `sql` the data for each single case. Just like: `$query = "SELECT * FROM sa_student_infoe, sa_student_edubg, sa_sase_result, sa_accounts WHERE some_field = ' . $_REQUEST['q'] . '";`